# Encryption and decryption not showing proper value

Tags: c++, linux, openssl, aes

my code is as follows

```
unsigned char aes_key[]= "asytfuhcilejnco";
unsigned char input_data[]= "Sandeep";
unsigned char enc_buffer[sizeof(input_data)+1];
unsigned char dec_buffer[sizeof(input_data)+1];

AES_KEY enc_key,dec_key;
unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

int main()
{

    memset(iv,0x00,AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key,sizeof(aes_key)*8,&enc_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(input_data,enc_buffer,sizeof(input_data),&enc_key,iv,AES_ENCRYPT);
    enc_buffer[sizeof(input_data)+1]='\0';//b

    memset(iv,0x00,AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key,sizeof(aes_key)*8,&dec_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_buffer,dec_buffer,sizeof(input_data),&dec_key,iv,AES_DECRYPT);
    dec_buffer[sizeof(input_data)+1]='\0';//a

    cout<<"input_data="<<input_data<<endl;
    cout<<"enc_buffer="<<enc_buffer<<endl;
    cout<<"dec_buffer="<<dec_buffer<<endl;
}
```

I am using input_data as the data to encrypt. 2 buffers enc_buffer and dec_buffer to hold encrypted and decrypted data. But when I run the following program, the buffers do not show the decrypted data matching with original input data.If I comment the lines "a" and "b" the encrypted and decrypted data  values match.But in that case the original data is shown in encrypted data.

output of the program

```
input_data=Sandeep
enc_buffer=X��8��Ȏ
dec_buffer=2���yT�
```

output of the program with a and b commented

```
input_data=Sandeep
enc_buffer=X��8��Ȏ��Yٔ�iSandeep
dec_buffer=Sandeep
```

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. That's a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like AES-NI. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Also see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption | C++ Programs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#C.2B.2B_Programs) for an example of using C++ and OpenSSL.

Answer (score 2):

AES is a block encrypting algorithm. So `enc_buffer` must be declared like below

```
unsigned char enc_buffer[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
```

The size must be multiplied `AES_BLOCK_SIZE` and greater or equal to size of input data.

You do not have to reserve place for the zero and insert the zero into the end of `enc_buffer`. It will contain binary data, not string charts, thus it cannot be printed like `cout <<  enc_buffer`. If you want to print it you have to think how to dump binary data, maybe in hex or in base64 format.